# Filter JSON object content

Tags: javascript, json

I've a json file which is response from an REST end point which detects objects in an Image. and in my file I need to get the bounding boxes and build a shelf data for Planogram.

Currently I'm stuck in filtering the output that I got. here is my code.

```js
let response = [
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 660,
            "maxY": 971,
            "minX": 582,
            "minY": 735
        },
        "label": "other",
        "probability": 0.698079
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 407,
            "maxY": 969,
            "minX": 326,
            "minY": 723
        },
        "label": "other",
        "probability": 0.6874929
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 569,
            "maxY": 963,
            "minX": 489,
            "minY": 728
        },
        "label": "other",
        "probability": 0.6783268
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 476,
            "maxY": 960,
            "minX": 395,
            "minY": 725
        },
        "label": "other",
        "probability": 0.6762803
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 507,
            "maxY": 643,
            "minX": 442,
            "minY": 405
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9600686
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 574,
            "maxY": 647,
            "minX": 479,
            "minY": 428
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9461142
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 466,
            "maxY": 662,
            "minX": 363,
            "minY": 421
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.94173825
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 679,
            "maxY": 647,
            "minX": 578,
            "minY": 432
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9386765
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 874,
            "maxY": 656,
            "minX": 810,
            "minY": 401
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.93829554
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 743,
            "maxY": 661,
            "minX": 642,
            "minY": 430
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9326571
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 393,
            "maxY": 664,
            "minX": 292,
            "minY": 427
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9322365
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 805,
            "maxY": 662,
            "minX": 743,
            "minY": 410
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9173948
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 332,
            "maxY": 661,
            "minX": 226,
            "minY": 425
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9157952
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 703,
            "maxY": 298,
            "minX": 603,
            "minY": 46
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.90590423
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 737,
            "maxY": 306,
            "minX": 669,
            "minY": 44
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9048507
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 251,
            "maxY": 319,
            "minX": 182,
            "minY": 28
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.90457577
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 822,
            "maxY": 299,
            "minX": 719,
            "minY": 35
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.903023
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 609,
            "maxY": 665,
            "minX": 539,
            "minY": 411
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8928388
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 943,
            "maxY": 298,
            "minX": 875,
            "minY": 29
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.88029706
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 636,
            "maxY": 301,
            "minX": 534,
            "minY": 51
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8651045
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 351,
            "maxY": 296,
            "minX": 252,
            "minY": 24
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8629094
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 874,
            "maxY": 290,
            "minX": 777,
            "minY": 18
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8621941
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 443,
            "maxY": 291,
            "minX": 343,
            "minY": 29
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8542643
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 562,
            "maxY": 302,
            "minX": 463,
            "minY": 46
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.85307074
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 948,
            "maxY": 653,
            "minX": 852,
            "minY": 391
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8488111
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 772,
            "maxY": 663,
            "minX": 702,
            "minY": 410
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.82573885
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 270,
            "maxY": 646,
            "minX": 176,
            "minY": 416
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.77004087
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 504,
            "maxY": 288,
            "minX": 409,
            "minY": 29
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.76433444
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 903,
            "maxY": 274,
            "minX": 847,
            "minY": 30
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.51238227
    }
];



var data_filter = response.filter( element => element.label  = 'soyaSauce')
console.log(data_filter);
```

Currently, when I run this, I'm able to get all the `labels` containing `soyaSauce`(I wrote this just for testing), but my actual usecase is to find the minimum value of **minX** and return that node in response.

for eg, if the minimum value of minX is 326. I want to print

`{
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 407,
            "maxY": 969,
            "minX": 326,
            "minY": 723
        },
        "label": "other",
        "probability": 0.6874929
    }`
 in the output. I'm able to get the minimum value by using the below code.

```
let values = response.map(function (v) {
    return v.boundingBox.minX;
});
var min = Math.min.apply(null, values);
console.log(min);
```

But I want to get the corresponding json object in output.

I've tried to combine both the logics and wrote the logic as below.

```
var data_filter = response.filter(element => element.boundingBox.minX = min)
console.log(data_filter);
```

unfortunately the output that I'm getting is as below. instead of returning a single json object :-(

```
176
[ { boundingBox: { maxX: 660, maxY: 971, minX: 176, minY: 735 },
    label: 'other',
    probability: 0.698079 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 407, maxY: 969, minX: 176, minY: 723 },
    label: 'other',
    probability: 0.6874929 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 569, maxY: 963, minX: 176, minY: 728 },
    label: 'other',
    probability: 0.6783268 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 476, maxY: 960, minX: 176, minY: 725 },
    label: 'other',
    probability: 0.6762803 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 507, maxY: 643, minX: 176, minY: 405 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.9600686 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 574, maxY: 647, minX: 176, minY: 428 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.9461142 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 466, maxY: 662, minX: 176, minY: 421 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.94173825 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 679, maxY: 647, minX: 176, minY: 432 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.9386765 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 874, maxY: 656, minX: 176, minY: 401 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.93829554 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 743, maxY: 661, minX: 176, minY: 430 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.9326571 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 393, maxY: 664, minX: 176, minY: 427 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.9322365 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 805, maxY: 662, minX: 176, minY: 410 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.9173948 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 332, maxY: 661, minX: 176, minY: 425 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.9157952 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 703, maxY: 298, minX: 176, minY: 46 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.90590423 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 737, maxY: 306, minX: 176, minY: 44 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.9048507 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 251, maxY: 319, minX: 176, minY: 28 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.90457577 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 822, maxY: 299, minX: 176, minY: 35 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.903023 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 609, maxY: 665, minX: 176, minY: 411 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.8928388 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 943, maxY: 298, minX: 176, minY: 29 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.88029706 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 636, maxY: 301, minX: 176, minY: 51 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.8651045 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 351, maxY: 296, minX: 176, minY: 24 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.8629094 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 874, maxY: 290, minX: 176, minY: 18 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.8621941 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 443, maxY: 291, minX: 176, minY: 29 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.8542643 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 562, maxY: 302, minX: 176, minY: 46 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.85307074 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 948, maxY: 653, minX: 176, minY: 391 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.8488111 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 772, maxY: 663, minX: 176, minY: 410 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.82573885 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 270, maxY: 646, minX: 176, minY: 416 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.77004087 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 504, maxY: 288, minX: 176, minY: 29 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.76433444 },
  { boundingBox: { maxX: 903, maxY: 274, minX: 176, minY: 30 },
    label: 'soyaSauce',
    probability: 0.51238227 } ]
```

please let me know on where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: `var data_filter = response.filter( element => element.label  == 'soyaSauce')` note 2 =

Comment: Correct, but it's recommended to use equality check (triple `=` sign).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to compare values inside `filter` callback rather than assign it

```
response.filter(element => element.boundingBox.minX === min)
```

In your case, it would be something like that. Note the filter callback

```js
let response = [
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 660,
            "maxY": 971,
            "minX": 582,
            "minY": 735
        },
        "label": "other",
        "probability": 0.698079
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 407,
            "maxY": 969,
            "minX": 326,
            "minY": 723
        },
        "label": "other",
        "probability": 0.6874929
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 569,
            "maxY": 963,
            "minX": 489,
            "minY": 728
        },
        "label": "other",
        "probability": 0.6783268
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 476,
            "maxY": 960,
            "minX": 395,
            "minY": 725
        },
        "label": "other",
        "probability": 0.6762803
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 507,
            "maxY": 643,
            "minX": 442,
            "minY": 405
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9600686
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 574,
            "maxY": 647,
            "minX": 479,
            "minY": 428
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9461142
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 466,
            "maxY": 662,
            "minX": 363,
            "minY": 421
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.94173825
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 679,
            "maxY": 647,
            "minX": 578,
            "minY": 432
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9386765
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 874,
            "maxY": 656,
            "minX": 810,
            "minY": 401
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.93829554
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 743,
            "maxY": 661,
            "minX": 642,
            "minY": 430
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9326571
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 393,
            "maxY": 664,
            "minX": 292,
            "minY": 427
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9322365
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 805,
            "maxY": 662,
            "minX": 743,
            "minY": 410
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9173948
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 332,
            "maxY": 661,
            "minX": 226,
            "minY": 425
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9157952
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 703,
            "maxY": 298,
            "minX": 603,
            "minY": 46
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.90590423
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 737,
            "maxY": 306,
            "minX": 669,
            "minY": 44
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.9048507
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 251,
            "maxY": 319,
            "minX": 182,
            "minY": 28
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.90457577
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 822,
            "maxY": 299,
            "minX": 719,
            "minY": 35
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.903023
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 609,
            "maxY": 665,
            "minX": 539,
            "minY": 411
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8928388
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 943,
            "maxY": 298,
            "minX": 875,
            "minY": 29
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.88029706
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 636,
            "maxY": 301,
            "minX": 534,
            "minY": 51
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8651045
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 351,
            "maxY": 296,
            "minX": 252,
            "minY": 24
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8629094
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 874,
            "maxY": 290,
            "minX": 777,
            "minY": 18
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8621941
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 443,
            "maxY": 291,
            "minX": 343,
            "minY": 29
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8542643
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 562,
            "maxY": 302,
            "minX": 463,
            "minY": 46
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.85307074
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 948,
            "maxY": 653,
            "minX": 852,
            "minY": 391
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.8488111
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 772,
            "maxY": 663,
            "minX": 702,
            "minY": 410
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.82573885
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 270,
            "maxY": 646,
            "minX": 176,
            "minY": 416
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.77004087
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 504,
            "maxY": 288,
            "minX": 409,
            "minY": 29
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.76433444
    },
    {
        "boundingBox": {
            "maxX": 903,
            "maxY": 274,
            "minX": 847,
            "minY": 30
        },
        "label": "soyaSauce",
        "probability": 0.51238227
    }
];



var data_filter = response.filter( element => element.label  === 'soyaSauce')
console.log(data_filter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Andrew. Such a silly mismatch of a less `=` :-(